# Finding the derivative of $h_x(t) = f(tx)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R}$. Let $h_x(t) = f(tx)$ I have it stated that "by the chain rule, we have $h_x'(t) = \sum_{i=1}^n D_if(tx)x^i$. Now I don't understand how they got this exactly, the chain rule says $D(f\circ g)(a) = Df(g(a)) \circ g(a)$, so if I write $f(tx) = f \circ (tx)$ we have $Dh_x(t) = D(f(tx))\circ D(tx)= \sum_i^n D_if(tx) D_i(tx)$

Answer (score 1):

You can write this as $$\frac{d}{dt} f(tx) = \nabla f(tx) \cdot x$$ which makes it look more like the chain rule. Or do it component wise: \begin{align*} \frac{d}{dt} f(tx) = \frac{d}{dt} f(tx_1, tx_2, \ldots, tx_n) &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} \frac{d}{dt} (tx_1) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} \frac{d}{dt} (tx_2) + \cdots + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n} \frac{d}{dt} (tx_n) \\ &= \sum^n_{i=1} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} x_i.\end{align*}